# rails 3 install error "File not found: lib"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

When installing Rails 3.0.1 i always get following error message, although i can use the installation.

I'm not sure if there's something wrong, I'm irritated by the error message.

Comment: Error in Windows: "file 'lib' not found"

Answer (score 69, accepted):

As in the answer by balupton:

[Ruby on Rails Beta 3 Install Problem on Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709683/ruby-on-rails-beta-3-install-problem-on-snow-leopard/3975020#3975020)

```
gem install rdoc
```

Follow instructions and then rerun

```
gem install rails
```

No errors occur to me now.

Comment: This worked with rails 3.1.3, ruby 1.9.3p0 on Windows Server 2008R2

Comment: This worked with rails 3.1.3, ruby 1.9.3p0 on Windows 7 Ultimate too.

Comment: Still the same problem and solution even with latest Ubuntu and Rails 4.0.0, I guess fixing it wouldn't be a bad idea for next rails versions, the error message should be made informative.

Comment: And here we are in 2014 running Ubuntu 14.0.4 and Rails 4 and this issue is STILL popping up.

Answer (score 8):

That didn't work for me, but this did `sudo gem install rails --no-rdoc --no-ri`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today. Serpenstage's answer helped and lead me to find this guide here. http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac

It installs RVM too, which is useful for running multiple versions of ruby.

Answer (score -2):

Did you install Ruby before installing rails?  I ran into the same problem until I went to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails#Get%20Ruby.  There are a number of steps you have to take before you install rails and I think this will help, if you are running it on the Ubuntu OS. Hope it works for you!

Comment: By convention post the content of any forum discussion in addition to the references.