# Installing Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 11.04 failed: file 'lib' not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I followed [this instruction](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) to install Ruby on Rails on my ubuntu 11.04, but always got this error message:

```
feicun@feicun-ubuntu:~$ gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-3.0.9
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.9...
file 'lib' not found
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.0.9...
file 'lib' not found
```

I googled this problem, which means the documentations could not be build, but rails 3.0.9 is installed. To solve this problem, I tried two method:

1. create a "lib" folder in rails' folder

   sudo mkdir /home/feicun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rails-3.0.9/lib
2. run "`gem install rdoc`" before install rails

But both of these methods are not work for me, these is still haven't lib folder in rails-3.0.9 folder.

This is my environment:

```
feicun@feicun-ubuntu:~$ which ruby
/home/feicun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
feicun@feicun-ubuntu:~$ which gem
/home/feicun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem
feicun@feicun-ubuntu:~$ which rails
/home/feicun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rails
feicun@feicun-ubuntu:~$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/feicun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/feicun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/feicun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/feicun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
     - /home/feicun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: This means that the documentation could not be build. Your rails 3.0.9 is installed. Try rails -v to see your rails version. You should see the correct version.

Comment: @vicent Yes I know the documentations is not installed, but I want to install them correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I followed these instructions [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129882/rails-3-install-error-file-not-found-lib)

```
gem install rdoc
```

then try install rails again

```
gem install rails
```

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

> sudo mkdir /home/feicun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rails-3.0.9/lib

Why do you use sudo to create a directory in rvm folder? I suppose there are some problems with permissions. Remove lib folder and run:

> mkdir /home/feicun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rails-3.0.9/lib

Comment: thx for your reply, Firstly I uninstalled rails with "gem uninstall rails", then create new folder “rails-3.0.9” by “mkdir /home/feicun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rails-3.0.9/” ， then create a new folder "lib" by "mkdir /home/feicun/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rails-3.0.9/lib", but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, all I did was revert to a previous version of RubyGems and it all worked; 
(I didn't look too deep into why this was the case but its become my initial troubleshoot solution, right after I make sure its plugged in ;)

Comment: thanks for your reply, seems it's a bug...