# Installing Rails: "File not found: lib"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

Whenever I try to install Rails on Ubuntu Server, I get the error, File not found: lib. Why is this?

Comment: can you give us more details, stuff like how, when where.. Thanks

Comment: Surely it says more than that.

Comment: I typed "sudo gem install rails" it seemed to be installing and then it showed that error. Specifically it showed: Successfully installed rails-3.0.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.3...
File not found: lib

Comment: use , `gem install rdoc` 
`gem install rails`

Answer (score 34):

Ubuntu 11.10, ruby 1.9.3p125, gem ruby 1.9.3p125

```
gem install rdoc
gem install rails
```

Comment: The mkdir business is too obscure... different unixes (Mac OS has its own path, etc).  Install rdoc first worked for me on a fresh (non-rvm) ruby install of 1.9.3-p194 and rails 3.2.3

Comment: This worked for me on OSX 10.7 :)

Answer (score 17):

I had the exact same problem. I tried the other solution suggested here and that didn´t work for me on Ubuntu.

Here is the solution:

## Ubuntu

**`mkdir /lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-{whatever your version is}/lib`**

Depending on which combination of environment versions you're using, some users have given the feedback that this works for them instead:

**`mkdir /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-{whatever your version is}/lib`**

Basically, the ¨[sudo] gem install rails¨ command expects the /lib folder (at the end) but for some reason it hasn´t been created yet.

If you're not sure what your rails version is for the part where I say {whatever your version is}, type up to "rails-" and then try hitting the tab button. You're on a Linux system, so it'll give you a suggestion or two. If it doesn't, try the alternative line given above. You'll need some try and error here because the directory structure is slightly varied in different versions of rails, it seems.

The source of this solution was the following URL. Hope it helps!

http://www.spritle.com/blogs/?p=915

## Mac OS X

If you're having a similar problem on Mac OS X, take a look at this other post as well. Sounds like your work-around is simpler:

[Ruby on Rails Beta 3 Install Problem on Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709683/ruby-on-rails-beta-3-install-problem-on-snow-leopard)

Comment: Pretty sure (in my case at least) it's actually `"/var/lib..."` instead of just `"/lib..."`

Comment: To make this answer more useful you should include how to get the value for {whatever your version is}

Comment: Re the /var/, it's actually not /var/lib/ruby/gems but /var/lib/gems/..  I HATE THE INCONSISTENT *NIX FILE HIERARCHY. But after the creation of four different directory trees I finally got this to work.

Comment: Thank you Simypy77, that solved the problem on ubuntu 11.04

Comment: In Amazon EC2's Linux distribution it appears to be /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-3.1.0/lib that's missing.

Comment: `mkdir .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rails-3.1.0/lib` worked for me, but I had to run it just after the rails gem is installed and the documentation begins to install

Answer (score 5):

Google has lots of information about this error. You can read [this](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=41111) or [this](http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/304-file-not-found-lib)..or [browse more](http://www.google.fr/#sclient=psy&hl=fr&q=rails++File+not+found%3A+lib&aq=f&aqi=g1g-o1&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=501cdaa261e6dee6)

**EDIT**

Found these on Stackoverflow itself: [rails 3 install error "File not found: lib"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129882/rails-3-install-error-file-not-found-lib) and the original one: [Ruby on Rails Beta 3 Install Problem on Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709683/ruby-on-rails-beta-3-install-problem-on-snow-leopard/3975020#3975020)

To summarize you need to run `gem install rdoc` before.

It might solve your problem!

Comment: Solved my problem on Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I kept receiving the following error message:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-3.0.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.7...
File not found: lib
```

After a lot of messing around reinstalling ruby and googling for answers I finally came across Amin Ariana's answer, upon which I ran `sudo mkdir /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-3.0.7/lib/`.

Success! Everything now works as expected:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-3.0.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.0.7...
```

According to a [similar StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129882#4129900), running `sudo gem install rdoc` has the same effect.

NOTE: To actually run rails after installing via gem rather than apt, you'll need to add the gem library to your path in your `~/.bashrc`: `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin`

Answer (score 0):

```
# sudo gem install rdoc
# sudo gem install rdoc-data
# sudo vim /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rdoc-data-2.5.3/bin/rdoc-data
```

rdoc-data version 2.5.3 is depend on your version.
My Marveric ruby path is /usr/bin/ruby, But my rdoc-data ruby path wasn't.
Then I change it.

**EDIT/**

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require 'rubygems'
require 'rdoc/data'

RDoc::Data.run
```

**/EDIT**

```
# sudo /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rdoc-data-2.5.3/bin/rdoc-data --install
# sudo gem rdoc --all --overwrite
# sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-3.0.6/lib
# sudo gem rails
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the actual issue lies within rubygems:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1958

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e7fc5d1cad27e47d3d0149a2b9a61d074c30f225

The default `s.require_paths` is, in as far as I can tell by the commit to fix the issue, `[lib]` rather than `[]`. So you end up with `lib` not found errors whenever you install a gem without such a folder.

Rails in particular, but not only.