# Installing Rails: "File not found: lib" On Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

whenever I try to install Rails on windows7 , I get the error, File not found: lib. 
please help me to solve this problem.

---

I saw other post with exactly this problem but in ubuntu in this site : 
[That link is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822052/installing-rails-file-not-found-lib)

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best tool to use for rails in windows is [rails installer for windows](http://railsinstaller.org/) and it comes with the latest version of rails. I just hope this helps you solve your problems